# Javascript: Remove last character if a colon

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Relative newcomer to Javascript and looking for a way to remove the last character of a string if it is a colon.

I know `myString = myString.replace('/^\\:/');` will work for the start of the line but not sure how to swap in the `$` character to change to the end of a line… can anybody correct it?

Thanks

Answer (score 142, accepted):

The regular expression literal (`/.../`) should not be in a string. Correcting your code for removing the colon at the beginning of the string, you get:

```
myString = myString.replace(/^\:/, '');
```

To match the colon at the end of the string, put `$` after the colon instead of `^` before it:

```
myString = myString.replace(/\:$/, '');
```

You can also do it using plain string operations:

```
if (myString.charAt(myString.length - 1) == ':') {
  myString = myString.substr(0, myString.length - 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. As a newcomer, I understand about using the backslash as an escape character but why are there a number of forward/backslashes in the `replace` statement?

Comment: @neilf: The slahses `/.../` is the regular expression literal. Inside the regular expression there is a backslash to escape the colon character, so that it is interpreted as a literal character and has no special meaning in the expression. (I corrected the code above, it had double backslashes for escaping the pattern to put it in a string, i.e. `new Regex('^\\:')`, your original code was some kind of mix between a regex literal and a regex string.)

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `/.../` format, only the backslash - thanks for explaining.

Comment: Thanks Guffa, you're epic! I used your Regex answer to manipulate other characters in URLs with ease.

Answer (score 42):

try simply with

```
myString = myString.replace(/:$/, '');
```

this will remove `:` when it is at the end of the string

Comment: I needed to remove any number of newline characters at the end of my string input. Your example served as a solid starting point. Then I used [regexr](https://regexr.com/) to test and refine. Finally I came up with **/(\n$)+/gm** and it seems to be working perfectly. Thanks for the simple and effective answer.

Comment: @Mentalist, it should be `/\n+$/`: the quantifier should follow the newline, not the end delimiter

Answer (score 0):

`$` needs to be at the end of the regex to match EOL.

`/:$/`